# Angular 4 performance & stress test

Tags: jmeter, single-page-application, performance-testing, stress-testing

I am looking for a way to performance and stress test my SPA.

I prefer an open source(free) tool to do so.

I have searched quite a lot(https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ajaxxhr-enabled-sites-jmeter) about the possibility to use Jmeter but i am still not sure if it is possible as this is an SPA and Jmeter works on the protocol level.

Comment: what is SPA ? can you clarify ?

Comment: by SPA i mean Single Page Application which is the type of websites that angular web apps are defined.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter is not a browser as such it will not:

- play URLs called through javascript.
- report time taken in UI by javascript to display it

But the good news is that you can record all requests at HTTP protocol level, 
all requests will be nested inside a Transaction Controller.

JMeter will play them sequentially and not in parallel.
So:

- response time will be sum of Main + child requests response time
- Load simulation will not be highly impacted as parallelism due to load testing will be simulated

There is also JMeter Webdriver Sampler that allows you to use a Real Browser

So by combining both approach you should be able to:
- Simulate load on your target application
- Have an idea of User Experience response times through [JMeter Webdriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/)

You can install both plugins using [JMeter-Plugins plugin manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/install/Install/) plugin.

Note there is a 3rd party plugin that provides parallel execution if you want the parallel execution but I'm not sure it's needed:

- https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md

Comment: I have read about the Jmeter webdriver sampler in the link i have posted on my original question but can it simulate loading times with a lot of parallel page loads? Like many users trying to open a web page at the same time, lets say 10000?

Comment: No it can't unless you have a huge number of machines, that's why I was proposing a mixed approach (95% use regular JMeter / 5% or less use Webdriver Sampler)